# How to create an instance with a child collection in one view create action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, kendo-grid, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm fairly new to MVC and Entity Framework.
My stack is MVC 5, EF 6, Kendo UI

Is it possible to have a data entry view that creates the parent object and one or more child collections of related data?

**For example:**

```
Retailer.<various properties> etc.
Retailer.PhoneNumbers.PhoneNumber
Retailer.PaymentsAccepted.PaymentType
```

My problems are not at the database, I do understand that the parent object needs to be created prior to saving a child item. Do I have to do this in two steps, Create the core retailer and it's properties, save it, then go to another controller to create the phone numbers etc?

My goal is to have one long "form" for data entry.

Sorry, I know this is vague, but the errors I'm dealing with have more to do with my lack of experience with MVC rather than an actual code error.

Thank you for any guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind collection properties to your form elements using a simple loop:

```
@model Retailer
<div>
    @for(var i = 0; i < Model.PhoneNumbers.Count; i++)
    {
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PhoneNumbers[i].PhoneNumber)
    }
</div>
```

Comment: So I'm not doing something "out of pattern" for MVC. I understand the syntax you provided, thank you for confirming. My issue must be with the Kendo Grid. Thank you - Now I know I'm going down the right "rabbit hole"... ;)